# months() operator in lubridate produces NA

Tags: r, lubridate

The following R behavior puzzles me:

```
> EndDate<-as.Date("2016-03-31")
> EndDate-months(2)
[1] "2016-01-31"

> EndDate<-as.Date("2016-04-30")
> EndDate-months(2)
[1] NA
```

Why does the first work and the second not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is on purpose.

You can read through the [lubridate documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html).

Specifically, you could do:

```
EndDate%m-%months(2)
[1] "2016-02-29"
```

This will perform the subtraction and automatically roll back the date to the first 'real date' in the event that the subtraction leads to a non-real date.

Mind you, if you instead wanted to roll forward, you'd have to do a little more work (as far as I can tell, I wish there was a simple operator like `%m-f%` or some other derivation of the already existing `%m-%`). But something like this will work:

```
EndDate%m-%months(2) + if(is.na(EndDate-months(2))) {days(1)} else {0}
"2016-03-01"
```